# how to integrate d3 with require.js

Tags: d3.js, requirejs

I'm having problems trying to integrate d3 into a require/backbone application. My main.js contains something like:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    d3: 'libs/d3/d3.v2.min'
    backbone: ...
    ...
  }
});
```

And my backbone view something like (in coffeescript)

```
define ['backbone','d3',...], (Backbone,d3,...) ->
  MyView = Backbone.View.extend
    initialize: () ->
      d3.somefunction
```

Console log says d3 is null. Is there a simple way to integrate d3 into this type of application?

Answer (score 51):

d3 does not call define() to declare a module, so the local `d3` reference to the backbone view will not be what you want. Either use the global variable made by d3:

```
define(['backbone', 'd3'], function (backbone, ignore) {
    //Use global d3
    console.log(d3);
});
```

Or use the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to declare an exports value for d3:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        d3: {
            exports: 'd3'
        }
    }
});
```

That will tell requirejs to use the global d3 as the module value for d3.

Comment: Important note for anyone coming upon this after January 2014 - d3 no longer works with requirejs shim to export a global object. You need to explicitly require it or set the global reference. Explanation here - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1693

Answer (score 4):

Since d3.v3 now registers itself as an AMD module if a compatible library is present, you'll need to use this workaround (from http://pastebin.com/d5ZDXzL2):

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "scripts/d3.v3",
        nvd3: "scripts/nv.d3"
    },
    shim: {
        nvd3: {
          exports: 'nv',
          deps: ['d3.global']
        }
    }
});
// workaround for nvd3 using global d3
define("d3.global", ["d3"], function(_) {
  d3 = _;
});

define('myModule', ['nvd3'], function(nc) { /* .... */ });
```

Comment: '_' seems like a really bad choice of variable names. You're just asking for conflicts with underscore.js.

Comment: @blatt not my code, but _ is a local variable and isn't used anywhere else in that define callback, so it has no impact on any global _. Besides, there really is no reason to modify that define callback. For readability, I agree, _ is probably a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but this works. I am not sure if it is the proper way of loading a module.

```
require(['libs/jquery', 'libs/d3'], function($, ignore)    {
  d3 = require('libs/d3');
});
```